# Need reason for the occurrence of following output

Tags: c

```
 main(){
   int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int *ptr=(int *)(&a+1);
  printf("%d %d",*(a+1),*(ptr-1));
}
```

The output of this code is coming out to be : 2 5 .
  I understand why 2, but why 5 is coming for *(ptr-1)?

Also ,

```
  main(){
   while(1)
   {
     if(printf("%d",printf("%d")))
        break;
     else
        continue;
   }
  }
```

This code is showing the output as :  Garbage value . How and why?

Comment: Please stick to one topic per Stack Overflow post.  Your second example is completely unrelated to the first.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` function returns an integer. Upon success, the return value is number of character written. And upon error, the return value is negative.

since the `printf("%d")` (inner one of `printf("%d",printf("%d"))`) will be executed first, it will most likely show some random value of a memory location. After that `printf("%d",printf("%d"))` will print number of values written during the previous call.

Example: 123456789010